# Phabricator Repository says it's unable to retrieve history and path, what's wrong?

Tags: git, permissions, phabricator

after creating a repo in phabricator, daemons running (phd start) it says that : 
Unable to Retrieve History
Ref "origin/master" is ambiguous or does not exist.
Unable to Retrieve Paths
Ref "origin/master" is ambiguous or does not exist.

I found (while googling this problem) a phabricator server that has the same problem as I do:
https://secure.phabricator.com/diffusion/P/repository/origin%252Fmaster/

do you guys know what's happening. I tried everything, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update Phabricator.

Management of `origin` was briefly broken in some situations when we switch to `--bare` clones (https://secure.phabricator.com/rP59922b7, Oct 29 2013) and restored in subsequent patches (https://secure.phabricator.com/rP4f20530, Nov 4 2013). A plausible explanation is that you last updated between Oct 29 and Nov 4 and are seeing a bug which is already fixed in HEAD.

If you're already up to date, or updating doesn't resolve this, come find us in IRC. This problem is specific to your configuration and resolving it requires more details. You can find information here:

http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Give_Feedback!_Get_Support!.html

(The link in your question is expected not to work; there is no "origin/master" branch there because the repository is self-hosted. If you access `/master/` instead, it works properly.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try updating it and I'll let you know .. .